# How to measure average execution time of a async function by running it multiple times in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, async-await, execution-time

I have a function that reads a huge file line by line and does something. I want to measure the execution time of the function in a loop to get an average execution time. I did something like below but it works only one time. It won't loop.

```
var start = new Date()

const preparePresets = () => {
    let presets = []
    fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(jsonStream.input)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return jsonStream.on('data', ({ value }) => {
            for (key in value) {
                preset = value[key];
                presets.push(preset)
            }
            resolve(presets.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id))
        })
    })
}

const measureExecutionTime = async () => {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        console.log(index)
        await preparePresets()
        var end = new Date() - start
        executionTimes.push(end)
    }
    console.log(executionTimes)
}
mesureExecutionTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in this:

```
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(jsonStream.input)
```

Try to fs.readFileSync first.

jsonStream.input - if this is same stream all the time I don't think you can pipe to it many streams simultaneously.